# Rails to_json - exact order of existing columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jqgrid, customization

I have a task to form JSON data for jqGrid. It requires a special format:

```
{
    total: 50,
    page:"1",
    records: "1500",
    rows: [
        { 20, "{2ae39c44-ca9d-4565-9e05-bbd875c1579c}", "Description 1"},
        { 23, "{e1aaf69d-1040-4afa-8995-fd15c3a591b3}", "Description 2"},
        { 25, "{e3df29c7-ef34-46ba-bf66-7838aca7c137}", "Description 3"},
        { 29, "{768ec164-28e5-4614-a259-63257b79e8e0}", "Description 4"}
    ]
}
```

So the basic rules for "rows" are: do not generate root object name, list fields without their names, list fields in exact order to bind to corresponding columns.

Can I force to_json method to modify output as I need?

Currently the to_json produces:

```
myobjs : [
myobj : { id: 20, uuid: "{2ae39c44-ca9d-4565-9e05-bbd875c1579c}", name: "Description 1"},
myobj : { id: 20, uuid: "{e1aaf69d-1040-4afa-8995-fd15c3a591b3}", name: "Description 2"},
myobj : { id: 20, uuid: "{e3df29c7-ef34-46ba-bf66-7838aca7c137}", name: "Description 3"},
myobj : { id: 20, uuid: "{768ec164-28e5-4614-a259-63257b79e8e0}", name: "Description 4"}
]
```

Comment: You can just override it and produce correct output yourself, can't you?

Comment: Yes, I can, but is there a standard way without overriding?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with a model-level `to_json` call, you'll need to build an intermediary data representation as @Paul said.  Something like:

```
class MyObj
  def to_json
    [id, uuid, name]
  end
end
```

And then in the controller:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def grid_data
    objs = MyObj.all
    json_data = {
      :total => objs.count,
      :page => 1,
      :records => 1500,
      :rows => objs.collect {|o| o.to_json}
    }
    ... send json as usual ...
  end
end
```

Note that I set your model up to generate an array, not a hash as you specified, as I think you copied that wrong - your JSON example above is not valid.  { 20, 'foo', 'bar' } is not valid JSON as "{...}" represents a hash, which must be keyed, and is not ordered.

Comment: Overriding `to_json` is an anti-pattern. Overriding [`serializable_hash`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000870/defaults-for-to-json-in-rails-with-include) is a more robust method of doing it.

Comment: Heh, guilty as charged.  But much clearer what you're doing for the next guy with the obvious override.  If you do the right thing as @x1a4 suggests, for god's sake, comment _why_.