# How do I do auto conversion of Rails time to Unix epoch time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unix-timestamp

I have a Rails app that makes heavy use of the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields.

I've found that something like `Post.last.created_at.to_f` will give me epoch time but I always need epoch time so I was wondering if there is some way to write an automated post-query filter that will do the conversion every time I called `created_at` and `update_at`.  Right now, every time I read `created_at`/`updated_at` I repeat myself, which is bad form, and has already caused bugs when I forget to do the conversion.

I'm using Rails 3.2.13 and Ruby 1.9.3p392.

Also, I can't just write `post.created_at.to_f` in my view since I'm using render JSON for my output.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using the ISO 8601 date specification, which is becoming the defacto JSON date format, specified in ECMAScript 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I believe approach suggested by @tadman is a better one.

created_at method can be as follows to do what you want:

```
      def created_at
        created_at= attributes["created_at"]
        created_at ? created_at.to_f : nil
      end
```

Place it in the models or attach it to ActiveRecord::Base. Carefully test it before putting to production.

Comment: Making `created_at` return a float is probably a really bad idea. You can't do any date calculations on it, rendering it virtually useless for a lot of operations unless you go through the expense of converting it back into a date again.

Comment: OP here.  The only things that need to see created_at are other machines.  Epoch time is so much easier to work with when exchanging times that I'm not going to specify an interface that uses anything else.  Also in rails going from epochtime back to a time object is EASY.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just make a method you can patch in to `ActiveRecord::Base`?

```
def created_epoch
  self.created_at.to_f
end
```

Then you won't have to remember to convert, you can just use that method instead.

Comment: That won't allow me to use render :json => @post

Comment: You can always override the [serializable_hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000870/defaults-for-to-json-in-rails-with-include) method in your model to include the custom fields you've defined.